# Perl - update mysql table without primary key

Tags: mysql, perl, sql-update, dbi

I have a table with no primary key.
I need to execute the following:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET tstamp = now()
 WHERE `col1` = 1
   AND `col2` = 'this';
```

In Workbench it throws `Error 1175` until I execute this line before the update:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

With this line it works just fine.

But when I try to do this in perl it doesn't work. I tried both

```
$dbh->do("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0");
```

and

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host:$port",$user,$password, { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0, sql_safe_updates => 0 })
```

but it still doesn't work.

How can I get this work in perl?

UPD.
I updated the code with @@sql_safe_updates check and commit.

The code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT @\@sql_safe_updates"); $sth->execute; while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) { print "sql_safe_updates before: ". $row[0] . "\n"; }

$dbh->do("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0") or die $dbh->errstr;

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT @\@sql_safe_updates"); $sth->execute; while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) { print "sql_safe_updates after: " . $row[0] . "\n"; }

$query = "UPDATE t1 SET tstamp = now() WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` = 'this'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$rv = $sth->execute or die $sth->err();
$dbh->commit;
if ("$rv" ne "1") {
    $query =~ s/\n/ /g; $query =~ s/  / /g;
    print "Failed to run query: $query\n";
   exit;
}
```

Output:

```
sql_safe_updates before: 0
sql_safe_updates after: 0
Failed to run query: UPDATE t1 SET tstamp = now() WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` = 'this'
```

UPD2. I checked the table - everything works after I commited. It is confusing thought, that $rv is 1 on successful `select` and 2 on successful `update`

Comment: You `do` query is not quoted. Is that from moving it into the question or an actual syntax mistake?

Comment: @simbabque no, it's just here. It is quoted in the script. I do not face any syntax error and have strict & warnings tunred on. Fixed.

Comment: Does it say anything? Any errors?

Comment: @simbabque no. I tried $sth->err, $sth->errstr but it's quiet.

Comment: Something similar works for me.  Did you forget to commit the update?  Can we see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What do you get if you run `select @@sql_safe_updates` before and after you try to turn off safe update mode?

Comment: @DaveCross Updated the question with this info

Comment: Use single quotes `'` or the q-operator `q{}` to not use do those backslash-at `@\@` things. :)

Comment: @pilcrow Actually I did. Wait. It works. But why the $rv variable is not 1 as with the successful select?

Comment: @pilcrow can you post this as an answer so I could accept  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a return code check error, and a missing commit.

Regarding the return code check, for a non-`SELECT` statement, [`execute` returns the number of rows affected, if known.](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute).  Zero rows affected (as opposed to an error) is represented as the special "zero but true" value "0E0".  In the OP's case, the statement was returning 2.